# Huawei HMS: upgrading hint isn't called normally

Tags: flutter, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-account

I would like to publish an app in Mainland China through Huawei AppGallery.
The app was rejected with this error:
"***We found that the upgrading hint isn't called normally when starting your app / logging in to a Huawei account / calling payment on a mobile phone with Huawei Mobile Services whose version is earlier than 2.5.3.***".

The app is developed in Flutter. I didn't find any guide on how to solve this error, so I tried to follow the Android guide. So, I've implemented this native code in the MainActivity.kt of Flutter:

```
MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, HUAWEI_CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
    if(call.method == "initJos") {
        val appsClient = JosApps.getJosAppsClient(this)
        appsClient.init()
        Log.i("JOS HUAWEI", "init success")
        result.success(true)
    }
    else if(call.method == "checkUpdate") {
        val client = JosApps.getAppUpdateClient(this)
        client.checkAppUpdate(this, object : CheckUpdateCallBack {
            override fun onUpdateInfo(intent: Intent) {
                val info: Serializable? = intent.getSerializableExtra(UpdateKey.INFO)
                if (info is ApkUpgradeInfo) {
                    client.showUpdateDialog(this@MainActivity, info, false)
                    result.success(true)
                }
                else {
                    result.success(false)
                }
            }

            override fun onMarketInstallInfo(intent: Intent?) {}
            override fun onMarketStoreError(i: Int) {}
            override fun onUpdateStoreError(i: Int) {}
        })
    }
    else {
        result.notImplemented()
    }
}
```

The method "initJos" refers to this: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-app-init-0000001055596854
The method "checkUpdate" refers to this: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-app-update-0000001055118286

Then, I linked these methods in this Dart class:

```
class HuaweiNativeApis {
  static const platform = MethodChannel('it.ppndrd.taskbot/huawei');

  Future<void> initJos() async {
    try {
      await platform.invokeMethod('initJos');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future<void> checkUpdate() async {
    try {
      await platform.invokeMethod('checkUpdate');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

In the main.dart, during loading I called both methods:

```
HuaweiNativeApis hna = HuaweiNativeApis();
await hna.initJos();
await hna.checkUpdate();
```

However, the error still persists, here the video the review team sent me.
[image]

Comment: The upgrade of the HMS Core is triggered when the capability is invoked. You do not need to call `checkUpdate`. And to solve your issue, could you pls send your apk for us to reproduce the issue? You can send it to hmscore@huawei.com.

Comment: Thank you @shirley, I will send it right now.
The first time I didn't add any of the code above and the app was rejected. Then, I followed the docs linked in my question, but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, may i ask is this problem resolved now? If that doesn't work out, can you re-send your apk? It looks like we can't download the file now.

Comment: Yes I solved the problem. The proguard-rules.pro file was in the wrong folder. I put it in the "app" folder, while it should be in "src" one.